# input field in horizontal form in bootstrap modal overflows out of bounds

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Simple horizontal form, the input form fields overflow out of bounds when display size is large. As you shrink the display, it seems to fall back into bounds. How do I ensure it stays within bounds?

Also, I cannot seem to get the label and field to line up next to each other.

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5bkncazz/

```
<button type="button" id="btn-request-endorsement" class="btn btn-default" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-request-endorsement">Request Endorsement</button>
  <div id="modal-request-endorsement" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Send an email requesting endorsement</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">

    <div id="endorsement-form-container" class="container">

      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email of endorser" />
          <label for="msg">Message:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="msg" placeholder="Enter a personalized message" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Email</button>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of CSS appears to be what causes the fields to break out of the modal bounds:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
```

This affects the `div id="endorsement-form-container" class="container"` element. Are you able to override this with your own `width:inherit` style or something similar?

### Label and Field Alignment

This is caused by the form controls having `display:block;` by default in bootstrap. You can override this by surrounding the label and field with a div that will act as a container for each form field. Then add in the following CSS to override behavior. A set width is also added to the labels here to make things look consistent:

```
label {
  width:70px;
}

.form-control {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%;
}
```

JSFiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5bkncazz/8/

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I simply removed the container class to make it bound nicely. Any thoughts on why the label and field alignment is not how a horizontal form should work - i.e. next t each other instead of on top?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution. I was just about to post an answer, but you can see how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/5bkncazz/5/.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the container class from within the modal-body class section fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I removed the container and added padding to it and it worked like a charm.